# CSS - Stacked elements overflow each other on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I have a column of elements each one is below the previous. A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
   <div style="position: absolute;">Really long text here</div>
   <div style="position: absolute;">Not so long text here</div>
</div>
```

Basically, my problem is that on smaller screen sizes the first inner div will overflow and will go inside the second div's contents and the texts from both divs will be on top of each other.

How can I prevent this? I wish to display my text in full and yet not allow it to overflow into its neighbouring divs.

Comment: You can add here the CSS you're coming up with and you may clarify what output you are expecting

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>    
 <style>
  #mainBox{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
  }
  #mainBox #box1{
   order: 1;
   align-self: flex-start;
   flex-basis: 60%; /*this is the width you wish the div to take*/
  }
  #mainBox #box2{
   order: 2;
   align-self: flex-start;
   flex-basis: 30%;
  }

  /*for smaller screens*/
  @media screen and (max-width: 520px){
    #mainBox{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="firstBox" style="position: relative; height: auto;">
  <div id="box1">Really long text here</div>
  <div id="box2">Not so long text here</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

with this you will have a responsive layout `flexbox` has many properties read up on it, its 2018 now a lot of browsers support it, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute` is going to limit you here unless you want to use some javascript. The idea with `position: relative` is that elements affect each others' positions -- absolutely positioned elements don't.

Your two best solutions in my mind:

- position your child elements relatively, then use `margin` or `transform: translate()` to shift them around
- use javascript to reposition sequential elements below each other.

Comment: that will work i will also provide another solution as well +1